# Grid Background Colour Based on Item Property

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

How do I set the background colour of individual grid items based on a property of the individual item? I have the following code:

```
<PivotItem x:Uid="PivotBlocks" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Header="blockx" DataContext="{Binding Blocks}" d:DataContext="{Binding , Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:DataSource}}">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Formations}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Point_ItemClick" Loaded="PivotBlocks_Loaded" ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="80" Height="80" Margin="0,0,10,10" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Shorthand}" Padding="5, 0, 0, 5" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</PivotItem>
```

Each Formation (item) has a `HasBeenSelected` property of type `Bool` that I want to use to set the colour, so grey if true, otherwise the users accent colour.

Comment: Have you looked at DataTrigger? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099694/listbox-item-wpf-different-background-color-for-different-items

Comment: Triggers aren't supported in Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use a *Converter* for this task:

Define a converter class in a namespace:

```
namespace MyConverters
{
  public class BoolToBrush : IValueConverter
  {
    private Brush FalseValue = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    public Brush TrueValue = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as Brush;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null) return FalseValue;
        else return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your XAML in *Page.Resources* define a key (don't forget to add namespace):

```
<Page ...
      ... some code ...
 xmlns:converter="MyConverters"
      .../>
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:BoolToBrush x:Key="BoolToBrush"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then finally you can use your converter with Binding:

```
<PivotItem x:Uid="PivotBlocks" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Header="blockx" DataContext="{Binding Blocks}" d:DataContext="{Binding , Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:DataSource}}">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Formations}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Point_ItemClick" Loaded="PivotBlocks_Loaded" ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="80" Height="80" Margin="0,0,10,10" Background="{Binding HasBeenSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBrush}}">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Shorthand}" Padding="5, 0, 0, 5" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</PivotItem>
```

Comment: @BenJ Because it's not WPF. AFAIK in WP8.1 Triggers are not available [reference one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/380b4b7b-72e2-4435-b7f7-0d2afca4eac0/winrt-cxaml-limitations?forum=winappswithcsharp), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14732723/2681948). This can also be done via *VisualStates*, but *Converter* should also work fine - it's one of possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but why create a new namespace here?

Comment: @blawford You don't have to create a new namespace, you can use your 'main one'. It's up to you. I just usually use different namespace for converters. Imoprtant is to point in xaml the namespace with converters (whatever it is).

Comment: Thanks. I don't suppose you know the name of the ThemeResource that is used for the background of the grid 'empty' letters on the zoomed in view of the SemanticZoom? As shown here - http://liupengs-blog.logdown.com/posts/194368-jumplist-semanticzoom-on-wp81 - I am trying to recreate the look of this, but without using that control.

Comment: @blawford No, I don't know.

Comment: OK, have tried implementing this as you detailed above and am ending up with a black background on my grid, any ideas? If I set a breakpoint inside the `Convert` method it doesn't seem to be getting there, is that ok?

Comment: No that's not goos - that's probably the problem. Have you added resources to your Page? Have you added `Converter..` in your Binding? Can you show somewhere your current code?

Comment: @blawford Ok, can you show also your ItemClass which you use for item template - this with HasBennSelected?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57600/discussion-between-romasz-and-blawford).

Comment: Found the error, was referring to slightly different named properties in the XAML to the class, silly mistake. Thanks for everything Romasz.